# android emulator can't start because .android folder deleted from the system

Tags: android, emulation

I am new in android 
in eclipse when I run avd it shows message

```
"PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\TEMP\.android/avd/bhadresh.ini"
```

and when I open the location where **.android** folder reside there is no **.android** folder in fact, there is not and my windows system settings are also changed automatically **.android** folder in any hard-drive.
now is there any way to regenerate **.android** folder

Comment: Do you mean that the AVD manager does not show up, or that you cant start an actual AVD? If so, try just creating a new AVD?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "hello", or "hello sir", or signatures on Stack Overflow. See "Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?

Comment: no avd can created but emulator can not started